# Flutter Runtime Error: PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod

Tags: flutter, exception, nullpointerexception, null

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingRegion(int, int)' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingRegion(int, int)' on a null object reference
at io.flutter.plugin.editing.ListenableEditingState.setComposingRange(ListenableEditingState.java:144)
at io.flutter.plugin.editing.ListenableEditingState.setEditingState(ListenableEditingState.java:161)
at io.flutter.plugin.editing.ListenableEditingState.(ListenableEditingState.java:64)
at io.flutter.plugin.editing.TextInputPlugin.setTextInputClient(TextInputPlugin.java:421)
at io.flutter.plugin.editing.TextInputPlugin$1.setClient(TextInputPlugin.java:135)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.TextInputChannel$1.onMethodCall(TextInputChannel.java:75)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown Source:12)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
))

Comment: any solutions ?